# Introducting a new probability measure

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, probability

I'm trying to understand what means :

$$ \frac {d \mathbb {\tilde{P}} }{d \mathbb P }   \bigg\rvert_{\mathcal F_t }$$where $\mathcal F_t $ is a filtration I guess (not explicitely mentionned).

they say they are introducing a new probability measure $\mathbb {\tilde{P}}$. Can someone explain to me what is the definition of it ?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context?

Comment: $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ is indeed a filtration. You may want to look at radon nikodym derivatives.

Comment: This is the Radon Nikodym derivative. It arises from the change of measure from $P$ to $\tilde P$. (Informally, think of it this way: $$\tilde P(A)=\int_A d\tilde P= \int_A \frac{d\tilde P}{dP} dP.$$ and thus $$E^{\tilde P}(X)=E^P(\frac{d\tilde P}{dP} X)$$ allowing to compute expectations conveniently in some cases). Filtration means measures are conditional on it.

Comment: @Vim Thank you all for the ideas, i'll check that. Do you have any intuition what means $$ \frac { d \tilde P } {d P } X $$ ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin i find $\frac{d\tilde P}{dP}$ quite intuitive, it is like if the probability of a "tiny bit" event is $dP$ under the original measure $P$, then the probability will be approximately $\frac{d\tilde P}{dP}$ times that much when you look at it from $\tilde P$. The same event may weigh differently under different measures, and RN derivative just tells you what the difference (or ratio) is.

Comment: @vim that was a nice explanation, would be better as an answer, but I cant convert comments to answers as mod!